# Why the items is not show inline?

Tags: html, css

Something strange happening... I am using `display: inline-block` to show elements inline. There was all ok until add added some new elements in it. Here is an examples:

[image: god]
[image: bad]

CSS:

```
section#main{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 7% auto 0;
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0.86;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}

div#video{
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 640px;
    height: 360px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block; 
}

nav{
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 360px;
    width: 270px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<section id="main">
        <div id="video"></div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
            <li>Keliaujame ?... JAV: ?ikaga / Chicago S01E03</li>           
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="comments"></div>
    </section>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nonamez/PfeP5/2/

What could be wrong?

Comment: +1 for the pretty illustration. Though a fiddle would've been more useful ;)

Comment: mixing % margins with pixel-sizes just leads to trouble...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PfeP5/

Comment: @MarcB there only in one place

Comment: @fizzydrink That version has no content in the left block, which makes it work.

Comment: It's the `vertical-align` default of `baseline` that is aligning the second box at the point where the text sits. You need to set `vertical-align:top` on your `display:inline-block` elements.

Comment: @tom van der woerdt i'm not sure I understand your concern?

Comment: @fizzydrink The problem only occurs when there's content in the box.

Comment: ahh, ok i see what you mean,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a vertical alignment issue, just set both elements vertical alignment to top

```
div#video{
    vertical-align:top;
}

nav{
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xHNJm/

Comment: oh, yeah, how i could forget about this... Last week i had the same thing

Comment: @musa - that works well too

Answer (score 1):

remove `display: inline-block;` from both

add `float: left;` to both

add a `<div style="clear: both"></div>` below the `<div id="comments">`

as demonstrated in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9BsS3/

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I always try to avoid using inline-block, just because of the ropey behaviour cross-browser.

I would use the following CSS (removing the display:inline-block; and use float:left in it's place (ensuring the parent element is also floated to ensure the clearing of child floated elements):

```
section#main{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 7% auto 0;
    float:left;
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0.86;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}

div#video{
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 640px;
    height: 360px;
    margin: 10px;
    float:left;
}

nav{
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    float:left;
    height: 360px;
    width: 270px;
}
nav ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
nav li {
    color:#fff;
}
```